# screenshot-tool crashed and my system is stuck with obscured text

Tags: release-loki, screenshot, crash

I was using the nice screenshot-tool on elementary loki and after taking a screenshot of a window it crashed without prompting for saving the screenshot. Now my system is stuck with the obscured text, also after rebooting.

[image]

Do you know any fast way to get back the text?

Update: the problem is a known bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/screenshot-tool/+bug/1592363).
A workaround is installing elementary-tweaks and press the button reset font in the font tab.
I had some real panic moments, I work with my PC. This bug is very bad in my opinion and the medium status is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of the OP, the original font settings needed to be restored.

Other suggestions:

- You might want to open the screenshot app again and uncheck "conceal
  text" (even without taking a screenshot).
- You might try to open a   guest session to check what has been changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried it. I tried all the combination possible in the screenshot app. And I restarted multiple times. Could be present a "deeper" switch to toggle? By the way, it's a very uncomfortable situation. X(

Comment: What if you open a guest session?

Comment: Guest session works fine.

Comment: After some panic I found a way to restore text. The font settings needed to be restored. This setting is per user so it did not affect the guest session. Thanks @lemonslice for helping me.